# Does this sentence I found in a book have a typo? -- "over her in her hands"

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning

In [Leigh Bardugo’s *Six of Crows*](https://books.google.dk/books?id=uqUwCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT80&ots=HbEeBFxdxN&pg=PT80#v=onepage) I came across the following sentence:

> She turned the lump of gold over her in her hands, then wrapped her dressing gown more tightly around her and curled up at the end of the settee.

What's with the ***"over her in her hands"*** part? Does it sound wrong to anybody else? From what I understood, the sentence is basically describing her as she examined the lump of gold in her hand, right?

Is it just a typo? If not can someone explain what the author was trying to say?

Comment: LInk to excerpt, title of book, name of author? There may be several editions with corrections etc.

Comment: Needs more context.

Comment: You shouldn't place in bold and within quote marks **part**, it is not in the original line. How do we know *you* didn't misread the sentence yourself,  if you do not supply the source?

Comment: I never implied that it couldn't have been a shortcoming on my part. anyway, it's all cleared up and I can live happily now, knowing that a book that I love has no typo.

Comment: With no further context, I would have said it was definitely just a typo and it should have said, “She turned the lump of gold **over in her hands**”. Now that I’ve gone and found the source (and added it to the question—the surrounding text is a vital piece of information to have!), I’m not so sure. A few lines before this quote, it says that _she held the lump up to the light_. If she’s still holding it there, it could be intentional that she turned it in her hands while it was over (above) her. It could still just be a typo, too. I don’t think it’s really possible to tell definitively.

Comment: It's either a misprint/typo or very odd phrasing.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think you're thinking too hard about this one...
When examining something small enough to fit in your hand, one tends to flip/turn it over back and forth, turn it around, plop it from one hand into the other, turning it over in your hands...

Comment: *She turned the lump of gold **over her** in her hands*,

Comment: @Mari-LouA *facepalms* thank you, for clearing that up. That's probably what it is. It's from Leigh Bardugo's Six of Crows.